# How to share a wordpress hompage?

Tags: wordpress

I have used a link to share the content of post to facebook but when i use it with the homepage it fetches a homepage's post data instead the home itself. So what modifications i should do to the following line :

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on facebook" target="_blank">
</li>
```

Comment: Which post you want to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are wanting to display the homepage's URL and title.

Why is it not working for you?

Using `the_permalink` and `the_title` fetch the values for the current record in the Loop.  On the Posts Page, there are multiple posts being rendered onto the page as it loops through the query.

But the page itself is not in this Loop.  Therefore, you can't use `the_permalink()` or `the_title()`.

**Do this instead**

Instead use `esc_url( home_url() )`, which will give you the root domain.  You can see the instructions in [codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url).

To get the site's title, you'all want to use `bloginfo( 'name' )`.

Using the function `the_title()` will not work for you here. Why?  Because the main page is not in the Loop.  Instead it's the posts that are getting queried and displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share the homepage, there is no need for the `<?php>`-part. Just give your URL in cleartext like `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=yourURL.com&amp;t=yourTitel" title="Share on facebook" target="_blank">`

Comment: But i want it to be valid for post and homepage conditionaly

Comment: You can't - not in this form. You have to include your code in two different templates, deciding if you're on the homepage or on a post's page. So: In the homepage-template put what I wrote above,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share the homepage use get_bloginfo(); function it returns all detials of your site. It take one parameter and return value,In this function you can pass different types of parameter like (name,description,wpurl,url,version,language,stylesheet_directory,template_url etc.) and get details of your site.

`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>&amp;t=<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="Share on facebook" target="_blank">
</li>`